# How to get icons from server and store them in android app

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app that shows different buttons, and icons for those buttons. The catch is that the buttons are added dynamically from an `ArrayList` that stores the options from the server. The way it works is as follows:

When you login, the server sends also all the options, and the app adds them to an `Arraylist`. I then use `GSON` to get a string and then the app saves the options to `SharedPreferences`, so you won't need a internet connection every time to get the right buttons. In the DB, I have the options, and another column where I have the icons for every button. I would like to know if there is any way to get the icons at the beginning from the server, as I am doing with the options, and store them into the app. So, when I create the buttons dynamically, to create the icons dynamically too, again without an active internet connection after they are stored. Thanks!

Comment: You can always write them to disk. See the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).

Comment: set icon from url, it's better than save file to local

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh if I set them from `URL`, is not the there an active internet connection needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a few ways to do it, the most important is the fact that you want to use it offline, so storing an URL is a no.
As Jakob F mentioned, you could just write them to disk at the start of the application and store the **path** to each image linked to button.

If you care about the disk size taken, you could have some fun with encoding/decoding the image from byteArray or Base64String, but that also depends on how are you storing the images in your database.

Comment: I have them stored as `PNG`'s. So the way to do it is to write them on disk and just save the `path`, so when I will dynamically add them, it will use the `path`, right?

Comment: You put them in one folder and you only have to remember the folder not all file paths.

Comment: I would like to contribute something from my research to this question. Since Android 11 is about to be stable and scoped storage will be mandatory, save all your icon in a folder within your app specific-storage folder (context.filesDir - kotlin) and use the folder uri to access the icons in it. Forget about the the absolute path.